# MacVim find and replace using regular expression

Tags: regex, macvim

I have a CSV:

```
21-Aug-96,S,S,S,S,S,N
```

The `S` are supposed to be `true`, and the `N` are supposed to be `false`.

I'm trying this command con MacVim:

```
:%s//^[S]$//tue/g
```

But it throws a "trailing characters" error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is completely incorrect.

You have "^" which looks for beginning of a line

And "$" which looks for the end of line.

Try:

```
:%s/,S/,true/g
:%s/,N/,false/g
```

Comment: What a simple solution. Thanks a lot, I had been scratching my head for a while :P